# Apache undefined symbol: ap_log_rerror

Tags: apache, apache2.4, mod-evasive

I am trying to install mod_evasive into my Apache 2.4
I run

```
apxs2 -cia mod_evasive20.c
```

But when i am trying to start the server i get this error

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 177 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_evasive20.so into server: /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_evasive20.so: undefined symbol: ap_log_rerror
```

Line 177 is simple

```
 LoadModule evasive20_module modules/mod_evasive20.so
```

Can anyone help me?
Thnx in advance :)

Comment: Well , finally i found that mod_evasive is not compatible with apache2.4.